# Redis Cluster: No automatic failover for master failure

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am trying to implement a Redis cluster with 6 machine.
I have a vagrant cluster of six machines:

```
192.168.56.101
192.168.56.102
192.168.56.103
192.168.56.104
192.168.56.105
192.168.56.106
```

all running redis-server

I edited /etc/redis/redis.conf file of all the above servers adding this

```
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
cluster-slave-validity-factor 0
appendonly yes
```

I then ran this on one of the six machines;

```
./redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 192.168.56.101:6379 192.168.56.102:6379 192.168.56.103:6379 192.168.56.104:6379 192.168.56.105:6379 192.168.56.106:6379
```

A Redis cluster is up and running. I checked manually by setting value in one machine it shows up on other machine.

```
$ redis-cli -p 6379 cluster nodes
3c6ffdddfec4e726f29d06a6da550f94d976f859 192.168.56.105:6379 master - 0 1450088598212 5 connected
47d04bc98ab42fc793f9f382855e5c54ab8f2e20 192.168.56.102:6379 slave caf2cec45114dc8f4cbc6d96c6dbb20b62a39f90 0 1450088598716 7 connected
040d4bb6a00569fc44eec05440a5fe0796952ccf 192.168.56.101:6379 myself,slave 5318e48e9ef0fc68d2dc723a336b791fc43e23c8 0 0 4 connected
caf2cec45114dc8f4cbc6d96c6dbb20b62a39f90 192.168.56.104:6379 master - 0 1450088599720 7 connected 0-10922
d78293d0821de3ab3d2bca82b24525e976e7ab63 192.168.56.106:6379 slave 5318e48e9ef0fc68d2dc723a336b791fc43e23c8 0 1450088599316 8 connected
5318e48e9ef0fc68d2dc723a336b791fc43e23c8 192.168.56.103:6379 master - 0 1450088599218 8 connected 10923-16383
```

My problem is that when I shutdown or stop redis-server on any one machine which is `master` the whole cluster goes down, but if all the three slaves die the cluster still works properly.

What should I do so that a slave turns a master if a master fails(Fault tolerance)?

I am under the assumption that redis handles all those things and I need not worry about it after deploying the cluster. Am I right or would I have to do thing myself?

Another question is lets say I have six machine of 16GB RAM. How much total data I would be able to handle on this Redis cluster with three masters and three slaves?

Thank you.

Comment: Close why? Whats wrong with the question? Some comments would be nice.

Comment: // , Who closed this?

Answer (score -2):

the setting `cluster-slave-validity-factor 0` may be the culprit here.

[from redis.conf](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/redis.conf#L830-L873)

```
# A slave of a failing master will avoid to start a failover if its data
# looks too old.
```

In your setup the slave of the terminated master considers itself unfit to be elected master since the time it last contacted master is greater than the computed value of:

`(node-timeout * slave-validity-factor) + repl-ping-slave-period`

Therefore, even with a redundant slave, the cluster state is changed to DOWN and becomes unavailable.

You can try with a different value, example, the suggested default

`cluster-slave-validity-factor 10`

This will ensure that the cluster is able to tolerate one random redis instance failure. (it can be slave or a master instance)

For your second question: Six machines of 16GB RAM each will be able to function as a Redis Cluster of 3 Master instances and 3 Slave instances. So theoretical maximum is 16GB x 3 data. Such a cluster can tolerate a maximum of ONE node failure if `cluster-require-full-coverage` is turned on. else it may be able to still serve data in the shards that are still available in the functioning instances.

Comment: This answer is wrong, 0 disabled the feature and ensures that a slave will *always* attempt to failover as master.